# Adding extra ticks based on sum of ybar stacked

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am trying to add `minor yticks` on my axis based on the end values of a `ybar stacked` plot. Here is where I'm at:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
Year    Far           Near      Sd
2012    1.7786e+01    31.762    88
2013    6.2690e+01    153.828   48
2014    2.9644e+01    25.0714   13
}\datatableD
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.15},
    ybar stacked, bar width=1.5em,
    point meta=explicit,
    xtick=data,
    every node near coord/.style={
        yshift=6pt
    },
    nodes near coords align=center,
    yticklabel style={xshift=-10pt},
    minor ytick=data,
    grid = minor
]
\addplot table [y=Far] \datatableD;
\addplot table [y=Near] \datatableD;
\addplot[nodes near coords*={\footnotesize $(\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta)$}, white, color=black, draw=none] table [y expr=0, meta=Sd] \datatableD;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like `minor ytick=data` returns a list of values from the column `Far`, but not for the sum `Far + Near`, any ideas ?

In the MWE, 3 minor ticks are added for `y = 17, 29, 62`. I would need the minor ticks to be added at `y = 17 + 31, 29 + 25, 62 + 153` instead.

Comment: Would you mind showing a mock-up of your desired final result? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the original post, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

I can give a statement to explain the issue. Others may contribute work-arounds.

By design, `minor ytick=data` results in tick labels for y coordinates of the *first* plot (only).

While this is reasonable for normal plots, it is ... unexpected (and perhaps wrong) for stacked plots.

Nevertheless, you need to create the list of required tick labels manually; the magic value `data` is of no use in this context.

I'll take a note on my todo list for `pgfplots` to reconsider `ytick=data` in stacked plots.